# SQL function for find orders with incompatable products

Tags: sql, t-sql

The problem arises due to 2 product types (say Bats and Balls) and two product ranges (say Baseball and Cricket).

I want to catch orders of Criket Bats and Baseball Balls and vice-versa.

I ran queries that found orders that had both a baseball bat and a cricket ball, using the HAVING clause (see code). But the issue is, the same order  may have had a cricket bat - making that order valid.

Instead, I would like to run a query which finds orders that have a Cricket Ball and any Bat that is not a cricket bat. This should account for the above problem.

I have order level data, line level data and product information data tables.

```
SELECT [LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr]
FROM LineLevelOrders
LEFT JOIN ItemInfo ON [LineLevelOrders.SKU] = [ItemInfo.SKU]
WHERE ( ([ItemInfo.Type] = 'Bats') AND ([ItemInfo.Range] = 'Cricket') ) 
   OR ( ([ItemInfo.Type] = 'Balls') AND ([ItemInfo.Range] = 'Baseballs') )
GROUP BY [LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr]
HAVING COUNT([LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr])>=2
```

Comment: Can you please add sample data to your question (and doing so might even help you find the answer yourself).

Comment: Tell us what you're ultimately trying to do.  I think you're trying to find improperly matched cricket/baseball items -- *BUT only if completely unmatched*.  Thus you want an order with cricket bats and baseball balls.  But you don't want an order with cricket bats, baseball bats, and baseball balls.  Depending on the details, there are 2 different directions I would go with an answer for you.

Comment: Hi @avery_larry, the only orders we want to stop are ones with:

1. a baseball ball and a bat which is not a baseball bat
2. a cricket ball with a bat which is not a cricket bat

any combination of balls or bats by themselves are fine. Similarly any order with a ball and multiple bats where one of the bats is correct is also fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could pivot first and then filter like this:

```
With ProductPivot AS
(
SELECT [LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr],
COUNT(IIF(([ItemInfo.Type] = 'Bats') AND ([ItemInfo.Range] = 'Cricket'),[LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr],NULL )) AS CricketBatsCount,
COUNT(IIF(([ItemInfo.Type] = 'Balls') AND ([ItemInfo.Range] = 'Baseballs'),[LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr],NULL )) AS BaseballBallsCount,
FROM LineLevelOrders
LEFT JOIN ItemInfo ON [LineLevelOrders.SKU] = [ItemInfo.SKU]
GROUP BY [LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr]
)
SELECT *
FROM ProductPivot
WHERE CricketBatsCount > 1 AND BaseballBallsCount > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set all these conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT [LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr]
FROM LineLevelOrders LEFT JOIN ItemInfo 
ON [LineLevelOrders.SKU] = [ItemInfo.SKU]
GROUP BY [LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr]
HAVING 
  COUNT([LineLevelOrders.OrderNbr])>=2
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN [ItemInfo.Type] = 'Balls' AND [ItemInfo.Range] = 'Cricket' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN [ItemInfo.Type] = 'Bats' AND [ItemInfo.Range] = 'Cricket' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN [ItemInfo.Type] = 'Bats' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think there is a "better" way to do this, perhaps using windowed functions.  But this should be functional:

```
-- This CTE will return all order numbers that have Baseball Balls
;with BaseballBallsOrders_CTE as (
    select distinct OrderNbr
    from @LineLevelOrders llo
    inner join @ItemInfo ii on llo.SKU = ii.SKU
    where ii.Type = 'Balls'
        and ii.Range = 'Baseball'
),
-- This CTE will return all order numbers that have Cricket Balls
CricketBallsOrders_CTE as (
    select distinct OrderNbr
    from @LineLevelOrders llo
    inner join @ItemInfo ii on llo.SKU = ii.SKU
    where ii.Type = 'Balls'
        and ii.Range = 'Cricket'
),
-- This CTE will return all order numbers that DO NOT have Baseball Bats
NoBaseballBatsOrders_CTE as (
    select distinct OrderNbr
    from @LineLevelOrders
    where OrderNbr not in (select distinct OrderNbr
                           from @LineLevelOrders llo
                           inner join @ItemInfo ii on llo.SKU = ii.SKU
                           where ii.Type = 'Bats'
                                and ii.Range = 'Baseball'
                          )
),
-- This CTE will return all order numbers that DO NOT have Cricket Bats
NoCricketBatsOrders_CTE as (
    select distinct OrderNbr
    from @LineLevelOrders llo
    where OrderNbr not in (select distinct OrderNbr
                           from @LineLevelOrders llo
                           inner join @ItemInfo ii on llo.SKU = ii.SKU
                           where ii.Type = 'Bats'
                                and ii.Range = 'Cricket'
                          )
)

-- This first query combines orders that have Baseball Balls
-- AND do not have Baseball Bats
select BBallsO.OrderNbr
from BaseballBallsOrders_CTE BBallsO
inner join NoBaseballBatsOrders_CTE NoBBatsO on BBallsO.OrderNbr = NoBBatsO.OrderNbr

union
-- Union the above with this query that combines orders that have
-- Cricket Balls AND do not have Cricket Bats.
select CBallsO.OrderNbr
from CricketBallsOrders_CTE CBallsO
inner join NoCricketBatsOrders_CTE NoCBatsO on CBallsO.OrderNbr = NoCBatsO.OrderNbr
```